# How can we read data from txt file and use that data in my code in Bash? This Not about comparing string

Tags: bash, shell

**code.sh**

This file contain following data

```
input="/path/data.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
 read -p 'Enter the name' name
  if(("$name"=="$line"))
   then  
  echo "matched"
  fi
done < "$input"
```

**data.txt**

This file contain following data

```
John
David
taker
```

I have 2 files. file one is `code.sh`  and second `data.txt`. The above code in `code.sh` file only read
data from `data.txt`. I want to access data from `data.txt` and conditional statement not working on `$line`. How can we apply operation on `$line` variable
The above code we do not comparing string we want to use data that we access from txt file. After accessing data we will be to compare string.

Comment: It looks like code.sh already accesses data from data.txt and stores lines in a variable called line. What problem are you really facing?

Comment: The data store in line variable only readable I do not able to apply operation on line variable

Comment: Please update your question and explain what is the real goal is.

Comment: I update the equation.

Comment: Your problem is you have redirected `"$input"` on the `stdin` file descriptor and then within the loop try to read `name` on `stdin` also. That won't work. Redirect `"$input"` on `fd3` and all is good, e.g. `while IFS= read -u 3 -r line ... done 3< "$input"`. You do need to fix your string comparison too, e.g. `if [ "$name" = "$line" ]` and I would fix the prompt too `read -p 'Enter the name: ' name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, your problem is you have redirected `"$input"` on the `stdin` file descriptor and then within the loop try to read `name` on `stdin` also. That won't work. You need to redirect input on another file descriptor so you can then read `name` on `stdin`, e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input="/path/data.txt"

while IFS= read -u 3 -r line                ## reads on fd3
do
 read -p 'Enter the name: ' name            ## reads name on stdin (fd0)
  if [ "$name" = "$line" ]
   then
  echo "matched"
  fi
done 3< "$input"                            ## input redirected on fd3
```

(**note:** the string equality test was also fixed as well as the prompt format for reading `name`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash test.sh
Enter the name: John
matched
Enter the name: David
matched
Enter the name: taker
matched
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This code give me error read illegal option `-u`

Comment: I'm not aware of any version of bash that doesn't provide the `-u` option for `"Read input from file descriptor fd."` What version do you have an what OS is it on?